# Existe algum ganho real em usar list comprehension em vez de um loop for tradicional no Python?

Tags: python, loop, for, sintaxe, estilo-de-codificação

Eu vejo muito por aí a indicação de uso de *list comprehension* na programação com Python. Várias vezes afirmam que ele é melhor que o *loop* for tradicional.

Pelo que eu estudei, *list comprehension* é uma espécie de loop for de linha única.

Existe algum tipo de ganho ao usar *list comprehension* em vez de um *loop* for tradicional?

Em termos de legibilidade, ele me parece ser menos compreensível que um `for` tradicional, principalmente quando se aumenta a complexidade com `if/else` e outras expressões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "compreensão de lista" é uma forma declarativa (que pode ser considerada funcional em certa medida) de fazer código.

Toda forma declarativa é mais expressiva que a forma imperativa, ou seja, ela diz melhor o que quer, em vez de dizer como quer. E claro, isso tende a ser mais legível, sob certo ponto de vista.

A legibilidade vem mais de indicar a intenção, não tanto por ser curto, até porque o curto nem sempre é mais legível. Algumas pessoas consideram que esconder oque está acontecendo é menos legível.

Legibilidade tem um pouco de subjetividade, então algumas pessoas podem achar algo mais legível que outras. Eu acho que é quase ou totalmente unânime que este caso fica mais legível que quase todos os laços. Sempre pode ter um caso diferente.

Isso é diferente por exemplo do uso de *map-reduce* muito usado em outras linguagens e até em Python. Quem acha essa dupla mais legível muitas vezes é porque ela acostumou usar, assim como quem usou *loop* acha ele mais legível, pelo menos em muitas situações. O primeiro impacto de algo novo é de que ele é ilegível.

Se a lógica é muito complexa não é para usar esse mecanismo na maioria dos casos. De fato fica menos legível. Ele foi criado para uma lógica simples, o resto é erro, mesmo que funcione.

Ser *one liner* (linha única) é bonitinho, é desejável, mas nem sempre a melhor solução. E vou dizer algo que não costumo falar mas é de extrema importância, ainda que fuja do assunto aqui. Hoje as pessoas mais novas na área estão com dificuldade de melhorar seus códigos porque elas estão inspiradas por referências ruins. **Quase tudo o que ela vê é ruim e ela não consegue desenvolver o tal do bom senso, ou até o bom gosto**.

[image: Pessoa com roupas extravagantes]
Tem área que elegância é o que fará a manutenção ser melhor.

Aí entramos na outra vantagem. Ao contrário do *map-reduce* que costuma ser mais lento, **em Python**, a *list comprehension* tem desempenho melhor que um `for` ou `while` em quase todos os casos (todos na implementação padrão de Python, exceto se um dos códigos não estiver bem escrito e o outro sim).

O laço será executado pelo seu código com diversas instruções executadas pela *virtual machine* do Python, que é um processamento complexo. Quando usa o mecanismo pronto para atravessar toda a lista é delegado para um código que foi escrito em C (em algum momento até invoca a VM mas o grosso do tempo é C). Já deu para perceber a enorme vantagem, né? Deveria ser mais do que realmente achamos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Verdade que o `for` tradicional tem uma leve vantagem na leitura quando se tem muitos filtros, eu prefiro criar uma função com todos os filtros e usar no *loop*, isso deixa tanto o *loop* tradicional quanto a compreensão limpos.

Tirando isso vamos ter ganho na velocidade, a seguir um teste com `timeit`:

```
import timeit

tradicional = timeit.timeit('for i in range(20): l.append(i)', setup='l=[]')
compreensao = timeit.timeit('[i for i in range(20)]')

print(f'{tradicional=}')
print(f'{compreensao=}')
```

Resultado aqui no meu PC:

```
tradicional=1.7931964859999425
compreensao=1.3583312549999391
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, neste caso específico (transformar um `range` em uma lista, sem nenhum filtro), poderia fazer apenas `list(range(20))`. Testando aqui, foi ainda mais rápido: https://ideone.com/iAZhHy

Comment: concordo plenamente, foi o exemplo mais simples que pensei pra ver a diferenção entre for e compreensão